# when I change eclipse installed JRE from default jre7 to jdk1.7, JSP files are not getting precompiled as well as I am not getting content assist

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

when I change eclipse installed JRE from default jre7 to jdk1.7, JSP files are not getting precompiled as well as I am not getting content assist.
After cleaning project, problems/markers tab doesn't shows any errors but when I run app, it throws errors on console.

Due to this I am not able to track the compile time errors And lack of content assist dramatically increases development time.

I googled a lot, but didnt got any answer. TIA.

Comment: you might need to change jdk compliance in java compiler of project properties.

Comment: Compiler Compliance Level is 1.7 and
Installed JRE is 1.7.0_51. I think its ok.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error neither I am getting any content assist suggestions. If any compilation error remains in jsp scriptlet i came to know it only at runtime on tomcat console

Comment: what runtime error got in tomcat console ?

Comment: its any compile time error like import missing, variable not found etc.

Comment: @Yagnesh.... Do you have any clue?

Comment: @Dnyanesh Try to see validation section under project properties, enable project specific setting and try clean build.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yagnesh...I have somehow disabled project specific validation for JSP files in my project.
Thnaks a lot once again dude!